# How to use a DI Container within a legacy class to create an instance of a new class

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

There is a legacy class in a huge Winforms solution which I cannot change the constructor (because there are lots of references to it).

However, I need to call a new class method within one of the methods inside this legacy class.

Below is an example.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class has been referenced by number of other legacy code
/// </summary>
public class LegacyClass
{
    public void LegacyMethod(string message)
    {
        LegacyHelper helper = new LegacyHelper();
        helper.Print();

        // I need to call my new class method here.
        INewClass newClass = new NewClass(new Logger());
        newClass.Print(message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Newly created class with interface. All registered with the container. 
/// </summary>
public class NewClass : INewClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NewClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        _logger.Save();
    }
}

public interface INewClass
{
    void Print(string message);
}
```

I am using Simple Injector as my DI container. What option do I have here to loosely couple with the newly created class?

```
INewClass newClass = new NewClass(new Logger());
```

I know I should avoid using Service Locator. (The Composition root is in another project)

Comment: I use service locator. It's either that or a factory to create the instance.

Comment: @GHDevOps are you saying use a factory inside the legacy code? Then the factory needs to be newed up the legacy class.

Comment: Square peg, round hole and a lot of technical debt. You are trying to apply DI but handicapping the approach. What are you hoping to achieve by trying to apply DI to this legacy scenario. Any refactoring here will need to bubble up and outwards to where it is being referenced.